# Outlook 2010 draft emails saved as RTF lose formatting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have someone inserting pictures and tables in Outlook emails. He is purposely changing to rich text format.  When he saves the email in draft, all formatting is loss. I have suggested that he use HTML to eliminate the problem but he declines.

What can I do on my end to minimize the compatibility problems this creates?

Comment: In RTF, anything that isn't plain text gets bundled into an attachment called "win.dat" or "winmail.dat", and a plain text version of the message body is used for the message.  That's probably what you're seeing.  You should be able to see everything if you open the message in Outlook, but almost all other email apps just ignore the attachment.  There are some utilities available that let other apps open the attachment.  Details here: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/microsoft-outlook-tnef.html.  Google tnef or winmail.dat for more options.

Comment: If he wants to have his emails readable by everyone then he needs to learn to appreciate that the type of email he sends *does* matter. If he doesn't mind you wasting an extra hour every day because he prefers to use one particular format over another then that's really his problem, not yours.